# Python: Load json atrribute as number

Tags: python, json, dictionary, load

I want to read a python dict from a json file where the keys of the dict are numbers (int or float).

This is my data.json

```
{
"number_of_uses":{  
    "weekday"   : {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1},        
    "saturday"  : {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1},
    "sunday"    : {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1}
}
}
```

I want to have python dict that is equivalent to something like this:

```
number_of_uses = { 
        "weekday"   : {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1},        
        "saturday"  : {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1},
        "sunday"    : {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1}}
```

I know that I can simply write a function where I pass the inner most dict and return a dict with ints/floats. But I hope there is some integrated function to do that for the whole file.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: To be concrete: I want every json attribute that "is" a number to be represented as a number (int/float) in the python dict

Edit: Added {} to my data.json

Comment: @adir abargill Not sure if I get what you mean. The json part in the question is only a part of my json file. I want every attribute in the json that "is" a number to be represented as a number in the corresponding python dict

Comment: I forgot those in the question.

Comment: The file you're reading is created by you or by somebody else? If it's the first case you could use `pickle` module to serialize/deserialize the object.

Comment: It's created by me, but it has to be readable by humans. So `pickle` seems to be no option.

Comment: does my answer meets you needs?

Comment: It certainly helps but it does not answer my question fully. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a one liner for this specific case...:

```
numbered = {k:{int(inner_k):inner_v  for inner_k,inner_v in v.items()} for k,v in number_of_uses.items()}
```

demonstration:

```
import json
json_str  = '{"number_of_uses" : {"weekday" : {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1}, "saturday"  : {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1}, "sunday": {"0": 0.1, "1": 0.4, "2": 0.4, "3": 0.1}}}'
json_data = json.loads(json_str)
number_of_uses = json_data['number_of_uses']
numbered = {k:{int(inner_k):inner_v  for inner_k,inner_v in v.items()} for k,v in number_of_uses.items()}
print(numbered)
>>>{'weekday': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1},
 'saturday': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1},
 'sunday': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1}}
```